# How to sort a list of floats into two groups that are optimized such that the difference between the sum of each group is minimized?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Assume I have a list of floats of the form:

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e, f, ...]
```

I would like to sort the elements into two lists (list_1 and list_2) such that the difference between the sum of each list is minimized. I'm essentially trying to find which two permutations are closest in size to one another.

edit: by 'size' I mean the sum of each of the two sub-lists

Comment: To find the minimum difference would be O(2^N)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to try this:  (**k** is how many sub-lists)
This code should work.

```
from typing import List

def partition(A: List[int], k:int) -> List[List[int]]:
    result = [[] for _ in range(k)]
    sums = [0] * k
    
    for x in sorted(A, reverse=True):
        
        i = sums.index(min(sums))
        
        sums[i] += x
        result[i].append(x)

    return result


print(partition([2.5, 7.2, 4.3, 9.1, 12.4, 10.5, 8.6], 2))

Output:
[[12.4, 8.6, 4.3, 2.5], [10.5, 9.1, 7.2]]
```

Comment: Could you comment a bit more about how you solve it?